# Anylogic - unable to open model

Tags: anylogic

Yesterday I was working on a file model in Anylogic.
Today I tried to open it and I get the error "Unable to open the model. Invalid project file format".

I'm able to open any other models. I tried to delete the .metadata folder but didn't solve the problem.
If anyone knows how to solve it, it will save me!

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the extension of the file you are trying to open?

Comment: .alp, same as yesterday same as the other models.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
clarify title of question, include [example] of your code
provide more information about the problem: 
results, tools, screenshots, 
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem recently.

In my case, the problem was caused because I copied and pasted Parameter descriptions into the Parameter Description text box from Adobe. Once I typed them in instead, no more problem.

The solution, as always, is to "Save As" frequently during model development.